# A Problem on Polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm dealing with the following problem:

> Let $R=\mathbb{C}[x]$ be the ring of polynomials over complex numbers.
>      Let $f_i\neq0\in R$ be three polynomials with greatest common
>      divisor $d$. Show there is $g_i,h_i\in R$ such that
>      $$A=\begin{pmatrix}   f_1 & f_2 & f_3 \\   g_1 & g_2 & g_3 \\   h_1 &
>    h_2 & h_3 \end{pmatrix}$$ has determinant $d$.

I know there is $u_i$ such that $f_1u_1+f_2u_2+f_3u_3=d.$ Now I want some $g_i,h_i$ such that $$g_2h_3-g_3h_2=u_1,g_3h_1-g_1h_3=u_2,g_1h_2-h_1g_2=u_3$$